# Highlight only current on single pages

Tags: functions

Goodmorning,

I tried to highlight the childs also in the navigation. I came up with this code. It works, but it will highlight all menu items in a row. What do I wrong or forget to add:

```
function add_custom_class($classes=array(), $menu_item=false) {
    if ( !is_page() == $menu_item->title && 
            !in_array( 'current-menu-item', $classes ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'current-menu-item';        
    }                    
    return $classes;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'add_custom_class', 100, 2);
```

Comment: why not highlight them using CSS?

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to do that isn't already covered by the CSS `id`s and `class`es supplied by default?

Comment: I thought it was easier this way. But how can I add active to the child with css than, because there is no specific class to style?

Comment: li.current-menu-item li a {color:red;}

Comment: There will be no class, so I can't add the css rule you suggest. So is it possible to do it with the function I have post above, but only get the active page highlighted?